# Can I make make4ht to copy the output.html file as index.html?

Tags: make4ht

I use the command "make4ht -e test.mk4 test.tex" to produce a number of html files named "test.html" , "test1.html" etc. This works fine. Now, I would like to have at the end of the process a copy of the file "test.html" named "index.html". Is there a command I could add to the mk4 file that does this?

Best,

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this build file:

```
local mkutils = require "mkutils"
Make:match("test.html", function(filename, par)
  local outputname = "index.html"
  -- support --output-dir option
  if par.outdir ~= ""  then outputname = par.outdir .. "/" .. outputname end
  mkutils.cp(filename, outputname)
end)
```

It matches the `test.html` file and uses `make4ht` internal function `mkutils.cp` to copy it to the new destination. The `par.outdir` variable contains destination of the `--output-dir` option.